# CSS: Apply CSS Style to Everything except Material Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material

How do I apply a CSS Style (`justify-content: center` or `box-sizing: border-box` to All child and grandchild elements, except anything thats Material and starts with <mat? Is there an easy to way to text search in CSS/SCSS?

We will literally have 500+ elements, need to effectively apply this.
Noticed that going into grandchildren inner-elements of Material, and applying  border-box or center can ruin its display .

Is there a mat keyword search I can apply? There are numerous mat div elements, `mat-input, mat-select, mat-tab, etc`

Trying to apply the css starts-with selector,

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

```
.container *not(%.mat) {
    box-sizing: border-box
}


<div class="container">
  <div class="document-holder">
    <div class>error_outline</div>
    <mat-input><mat-input>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.container *:not([class^="mat"]) {
    background: red;
}
```

That's the code you might be searching for.

`[class^="mat"]` will match to any element which has a class starting with `mat`.

`[class*="mat"]` will match to any element having `mat` anywhere in the class name.

Use either of them according to your situation.

Comment: I would recommend using "mat-" instead of "mat".

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try to reset it afterwards.

You can use your selector

```
.container * {
  display:flex;
}
```

and after that add the previous value for `mat-input`

```
.container * {
  display:flex;
}
.mat-input {
  display:flex; /* or whatever it was previously */
}
```

Comment: see, not sure if they were on flex or bordersize, wanted to revert

Answer (score 3):

Not the exact solution you are looking for, and assuming you have different elements starting with "mat", not only `mat-input`, I would add a class to all of them, and use the `:not` keyword. Something like:

```
.container *:not(.mat) {
    display:flex;
}


<div class="container">
  <div class="document-holder">
    <div class>error_outline</div>
    <mat-input class="mat"><mat-input>
```

Something visual can be seen in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wats134e/).

If you only have a low number of "mat" elements, you can also use the `:not` keyword several times, something like:

```
.container *:not(mat-input):not(mat-output) {
    display:flex;
}


<div class="container">
  <div class="document-holder">
    <div class>error_outline</div>
    <mat-input><mat-input>
    <mat-output></mat-output>
```

Comment: interesting, instead of listing all the mat elements, can I do a mat keyword search?

Comment: In [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) of the not operator, I cannot see a default way to do it

Answer (score 3):

Well, what you want is a really really bad way to workaround things since it makes your stylings hard to maintain and may lead to unexpected issues, but hey, you can use this css to set `box-sizing` property to all elements except the ones starts with `mat-`.

```
.container *:not([class^="mat-"]) {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you asked for SCSS solution. In this example I've used SASS [List](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/lists) and [@each](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each)

```
$matList: input, select, tab; /* list of `mat-`s */
$notList: ""; /* empty variable */

/* adding :not() statmant for each $matList item */
@each $not in $matList {
  $notList: $notList + ':not(mat-#{$not})';
}

/* gets the result of $notList */
.container *#{$notList} {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Anyway, you still have to insert the list of `mat-` tags (only part after "-") in $matList, but in much easier form. Otherwise you will have to use JavaScript to get the list of all `map-` elements.

After compile you will get

```
.container *:not(mat-input):not(mat-select):not(mat-tab) {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container *:not([class^="mat-"]),
.container *:not([class*=" mat-"]) {
    background: red;
}
```

This will match all elements with a class list beginning with "mat-", as well as elements with a class list containing " mat-". That space is important to avoid accidentally targetting a "format-" class, for instance.